# Property of equivalent measures

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, equivalent-metrics

Say I have a probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}$) with two equivalent measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.
Consider two sets $A, B \in \Omega$. I know that $\mathbb{P}\left[A\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[B\right] = k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}\left[A\right] = z \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is there something (if it can be true) that allows me to say $\mathbb{Q}\left[B\right] = z$? Is it trivial from the definition of equivalent measures?

Comment: No, there isn't. Being equivalent means that the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f=\frac{dP}{dQ}$ can be chosen to be never zero, but from here you can construct a counter-example for your question

Comment: No, in fact it is false in general. (I encourage you to try and construct a counter-example. For instance, try playing with discrete measures and see what you can find.)

Comment: Thank you! I will try to come up with counter-examples!